# CSS zoom image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to zoom the background image on hover.

The code below does not zoom the background image. Instead it zooms the panels which are on the front. 
The problem is, that I do not have any div-tag for the img. I add a class to the body.

```
.imageNeutral{
    background-image: url('../App/Images/nature.jpg');
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: auto;

}

.imageNeutral{
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 3s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease; 
    transition: all 3s ease;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.imageNeutral:hover
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); 
    transform:scale(1.05);
}
```

in javascript:

```
 $("body").addClass('imageNeutral');
```

all other elements are zoomed, but not the image. I just want to zoom the image.

**.imageNeutral img:hover** does also not work.

do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you try to search this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set background size using `background-size` for both normal and hovered and animate it.

```css
.imageNeutral {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/');
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}
.imageNeutral:hover {
    -webkit-background-size: 120% auto;
    background-size: 120% auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="imageNeutral"></body>
```

**Edit:** Changed tags to match the ones provided.

Comment: I can´t use a div-tag because I havee many ng-views, and I change the background image in the directive

Comment: I have updated the tags to match yours.

Comment: thanks for the post.

Answer (score -1):

Make two background images - normal and zoomed
An on hover change the background image. That should work.